# What are some Desktop Enviroments that are 100% open-source and touch-friendly?

Tags: desktop-environments

It needs to be

- **100% open source**
- **It must NOT recommend any closed/shared source software**

Please post in the following format:

- Desktop environment name
- A screenshot of the desktop environment
- Why you should use it
- How to get/install (without adding ppas/repos with non-free software and/or installing non-free software or metapackages that need non-free software or softwa-re that needs non-free software)  it
- Your opinion of why/why not someone should use this desktop environment
- For what people it is (etc enthusiasts, normal people, or people who find computers hard to use.)

Please do not post duplicates unless you have a better review of them. You can not post just windows managers alone, but you can post window managers and desktop environments combined (etc KDE/Openbox). The definition of touch-friendly, in this case would be

- Big icons and text
- **Usable with touchscreens**

Comment: Are we putting a bit too much stress on the answer format? This is a community resource where the participants are (_mostly_) volunteers. I myself consider me to be responsible to pick the necessary piece from the provided answers.

Comment: I mean to provide a Q/A format like [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available/65223#65223). While that is a great question, this question is meant to be like a filter for those who have touchscreens and bad/unusable mouses/keyboards and do not want to use any non-free software. It's hard to know whenever the desktop enviroment is open-source and is touch-friendly, so I created this question.

Comment: Also many people still use Precise.

Answer (score 2):

All Linux distributions are 100% open-source. They just have their own pre-installed software. You can do and undo anything in the system, as that is in its nature. It's like Android. Google makes it one way, but you can gain root access to change it, and they like and allow that.

**Ubuntu**

It's open-source but owned by Canonical. You can do anything you want with it, with or without root, but in different respects.

[image]

**Screenshot ::** 
*Why You Should Use It*

Ubuntu is great because it's something new. It's not copying any other distro. Kubuntu runs like Windows, and every other Linux distro is based off of something. Ubuntu is something new, something that we get to talk about, it's advanced, stable and pretty hardcore awesome. You can get a lot of work done with a stable OS. I personally favor this.

Comment: I mean without adding non-free software (ie nvida-common is software installed on ubuntu, as a driver.) Please follow the format posted in the question. I meant by "100% precent open-source" something that would go into a FSF distro.

Comment: I posted my answer and now I'm adding more info. All distros come with something pre-installed like this. If you give me specifics, I can tell you. I can do anything on Ubuntu, as "100% open-source."

Comment: This is a whole distro, not just a Desktop Enviroment.

Comment: Okay, have you tried KDE?

Comment: I meant maybe the question could be edited to focus on KDE in general, not just Ubuntu. Also someone else is posting about KDE, so remeber: no duplicates unless you have a better answer.

Comment: Also, this answer is a good idea of what the answer should look like, but should still focus on a desktop enviroment (kde for instance is a desktop enviroment, but fedora is a distro).

Comment: How about KDE, then? It's my personal favorite aside from Unity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Ultimate Edition. That I know for sure is considered 100% "real" Linux. Not owned by anyone [org.-wise], no pre-owned or installed software.

Comment: I'm looking for desktop enviroments (kde gnome etc.), not whole distros (fedora opensuse etc etc.)

Comment: Yes, you can get it as a desktop environment... - That's using KDE.

Comment: It needs to be free software. The focus should be on the desktop enviroment, not the distro. See the format posted on the question.

Comment: Everything on Linux is free -- not sure where you're getting at. Linux and anything Linux is mostly free and has mostly free software. Also, it cannot "be" free if it's an environment, so it's not really clear what you meant in the above comment.

Comment: I mean freedom as in free software (i.e. free software license) not free as in free price (i.e. a program that is freeware but doesn't share it's source code.)

Comment: "Linux" itself is freely licensed, that's for any distro. Just because it's developed by a company doesn't mean it's not open source. Think of it this way. If you know it's Linux or Linux based, it's 100% open-source. You just may need to handle them differently because of DE.

Comment: But if that doesn't answer your question, someone with more knowledge on that can answer. But all Linux ditros are free the way in which you mention.